# sudo apt update error: 404 Not Found

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

It shows the following error:

```
Err:2 https://cli.github.com/packages stable/main amd64 gh amd64 2.14.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.199.108.153 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/pool/main/g/gh/gh_2.14.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.199.108.153 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

But I can ping 185.199.108.153 well.
When I run $sudo apt update, it shows the following error:

```
Err:4 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I run the following:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23F3D4EA75716059
```

It shows the following:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.m9dSx1oUbg/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23F3D4EA75716059
gpg: key 23F3D4EA75716059: "GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Then I run $sudo apt-get update, the same result comes out.

What should I do to work around it?

Comment: Pinging a server will not tell you whether a file exists or not, which is why you can ping without error. The `.deb` file that is specified in the package list does not exist on GitHub (as far as I can tell), which is why you cannot download it 

Comment: How to solve it? Or just let it be?

Comment: If the file is being specified by a repository's release file, then chances are other people have the very same issue and someone will fix the problem in the near future. If this continues to be a problem for too long, it may be worthwhile to remove the erroneous repository for a while so that other updates can happen without messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try the instructions given in this page, It might help.

https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md#debian-ubuntu-linux-raspberry-pi-os-apt